# IIS 7.0 Session Sharing among different applications

Tags: iis-7, share, application, session

We have created two web applications, one nested inside another(Our main web app is the outer one, and we have a cms inside, or below it).  We're trying to get session sharing between the applications(using state server option) as mentioned here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sharedsession.aspx

Session is working for each one separately, however when we cross the boundary between them, we lose the session data.

Both web.config files have the same machine key entry, and I'm trying to set the application path as mentioned here:
** Can't display second link **

I'm not sure if I'm going down the right path or not.  Ideally I'd like to do something like this in code:

On Main Website Side: Session["SomeVar"] = SomeData;

On the CMS side(nested inside): Display(Session["SomeVar"]); // this would display SomeData

We could also go in reverse, set the session variable cms side, display it Main Web Site side).

Comment: second link from above: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/gopenath/page107182007032219am/page1.aspx

Comment: You solved this problem? In a similar case, I solve with the guidelines of that link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx You are not remove any authentication module in the sub application?